# Multiple "InfoWindow" for array of "markers" on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Using Google Maps API to add an infoWindow to each marker. Markers come from an array.

Although, infoWindow only shows up for the first marker, not the others. Why? Thanks.

```
function set_markers(array) {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var single_location = array[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(single_location[1], single_location[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: single_location[0]
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ""
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<h3>'+this.title+'</h3>');
        infowindow.open(map,this);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you showing the actual code here? Looks like infowindow is undefined in your call to addListener - or is it a global not shown?

Comment: @SteveO'Connor "var infowindow" is defined inside the "for" loop. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @murid you're creating your markers and infowindows within a loop.  But then you only have a single event listener on your markers, i.e. only on the very last one.  Move the event listener inside the loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function set_markers(array) {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        var single_location = array[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(single_location[1], single_location[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: single_location[0]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent('<h3>' + this.title + '</h3>');
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}
```

This is untested since you didn't post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).